# Quickly Rename Current Workspace

Tags: workspaces

I can rename my workspace by going into my WorkSpace Switcher Preferences:

[image]

Does anyone know a quicker way to rename my current workspace (Maybe something with GnomeDo)?

Comment: For lurkers like me wondering how the shown preferences dialog helps in renaming, the trick is to double-click the name in the 'Workspace names' listing. There is no contextual menu in this listing nor in the workspace display, and there is no F2 renaming in this dialog either.

Comment: @Urhixidur Do you know if it is possible to change the workspace names in Gnome 3?

Comment: I found out that you need to change the dconf key 'org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences workspace-names'. You can do this manually with the dconf editor or via an extension, such as https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/ (Gnome tweak tool -> Extensions -> Settings bars)

Comment: @cheflo My workspace display is under gnome 3, I think.  (Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using metacity, you could edit or create a bash script to edit it directly in gconf I guess:

```
~/.gconf/apps/metacity/workspace_names/%gconf.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently this *is* the fastest way. Maybe you might be better off reporting a wishlist item against Synapse (GNOME-Do was replaced by that).